# What do the double- or triple-checkers do when a launch is not scheduled?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, launch-sequence, ground-crew

Leading up to every manned launch, there is personnel dedicated to making sure their colleagues do everything correctly in accordance to checklists they usually have on hand.

See for example the ground crew of Spacex's Dragon demo 2 when closing the hatch (around 2:12:23 in this video)

But crewed launches aren't that frequent.

- **What is the professional occupation of these people?**
- **What do they do the rest of the year?**

Comment: I suspect that they mostly develop the checklists and practice using the checklists.